# GNUHealth installation fails

Tags: gpg, postgresql

Today trying to install GNUHealth on my Fedora 27 (32bit). after creating user I tried to verify PostgreSQL.
here's a file pg_hba.conf in /var/lib/pgsql/data. This shows following lines
[image]

In this file i found no line containing `local all all trust`

`gpg --recv-key 0xC015E1AE00989199` returns this

```
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: no keyserver known (use option --keyserver)
gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad URI
```

`gpg --with-fingerprint --list-keys 0xC015E1AE00989199`gives

```
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: error reading key: public key not found
```

After downloading the detached signatures I tried to verify the package by `gpg --verify gnuhealth-3.2.9.tar.gz.sig gnuhealth-latest.tar.gz`
this too shows

```
    gpg: error reading key: public key not found
```

Then I wrote this of installation `./gnuhealth-setup install`

 this returns `2018-05-20 07:08:03 [INFO] Starting GNU Health 3.2.9 installation...
2018-05-20 07:08:03 [INFO] Checking requirements
 -> Looking for wget... wget is /usr/bin/wget
 -> Looking for 2to3... 2018-05-20 07:08:03 [ERROR] 2to3 command not found. Please install it or check your PATH variable
2018-05-20 07:08:03 [INFO] Bailing out !
2018-05-20 07:08:03 [INFO] Cleaning up temp directories at 
2018-05-20 07:08:03 [INFO] removing base dir at`

So I failed in installation. what should be done in this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `2to3` is not installed by default and can be installed by using

```
yum install python-tools
```

Now running `./gnuhealth-setup install` should allow it to complete